# Strange visual studio 2008 C++ compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, comments

I have three lines of code:

```
 //int pi;
 activation->structSize = sizeof(rmsActivationT);
 int pi; //program wont compile with this here
```

every time I uncomment the second int pi and comment the first int pi I get this error: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'. When i uncomment this first int pi and comment the second int pi, my compiler doesn't complain anymore. This error has been bothering me for almost a full day now any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Visual studios 2008
Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: Maybe you should show more than that...

Comment: Could you show some context, and point out exactly which line the error message points to?  Right now, I'd be doing nothing but wildly speculating.

Comment: can you do a favor for me and add a blank line between each and try your various comment/uncomment/compile options?

Comment: I've already seen such wizardry with VS 2005. Roughly twice a year... Clean solution, restart computer... sometimes it works; sometimes I left the swapped lines.

Comment: @David, the compiler points right at the bottom line. I have checked the activation struct for missing ';' and haven't found any so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you, perhaps, compiling the code as C instead of C++? C (prior to C99, which Visual Studio doesn't support) required that all definitions in a block precede any other statements.

Comment: You beat me to it.  This is almost certainly the problem, as that is exactly the error that will result.  If the file is a .cc/.cpp file, check the "C++/Advanced/Compile As" setting in the project properties.   If your file is a ".C" file, remember that Windows is not case-sensitive, you will need to rename the source files or use the above setting to force C++ compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The compilation errors were:

*main.cpp(325): error C2601: 'FLAG' : local function definitions are illegal

main.cpp(323): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched

main.cpp(326): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'main.cpp(323)' was matched*

But there was nothing wrong with my code. I counted all brackets and the number matched. There weren't any function inside another function.

I solved it by removing all "//" comments from the source code. It seems that the reason for that is bad line formatting which causes the compiler to miss a line break, so the line after a comment is treated as a comment as well.

For example:

```
// This is a comment

This_is_a_line;
```

is treated as:

```
// This is a comment This_is_a_line;
```