# Visual Studio 2008 Windows SDK Compiler Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I've recently run into a compiler error.

For some reason, when I try to compile my solution in Visual Studio 2008 (referencing the 7.1 SDK), I get a ton of errors that look like this:

> error C2040: 'WCHAR' : 'const WCHAR *' differs in levels of
>   indirection from 'wchar_t'

as well as this:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCTSTR'

I am a bit confused by these messages, because the rest of my team is able to compile this same code with no issue.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I seem to be compiling as C++ and the files are also named with the .cpp extension (which is the issue mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354490/strange-visual-studio-2008-c-compiler-error)), so I am not sure what else might be causing this error.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Here is a simple sample program that should but will NOT build for me:

**Note: This only occurs when windows.h is included**

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors that appear:

> Error 1   error C2040: 'WCHAR' : 'const WCHAR *' differs in levels of
>   indirection from 'wchar_t'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h
>
> Error 2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'PCTSTR'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h
>
> Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h
>
> Error 4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h
>
> Error 5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h

Comment: can you compile the solution from the SDK commandline environment?

Comment: Did you run the Windows SDK 7.1 Configuration Tool (located on your Start menu in the Windows SDK programs group) to configure your VS2008 environment to use the SDK rather than the default toolchain, headers, and libs of the VS install ? You may want to verify that.

Comment: @rubenvb I have not tried that yet. While searching for an answer to this issue, I think I remember reading somewhere that a solution was to reinstall VS2008. I'll try that and get back to you on the commandline option (if that was the only way to compile, though, it would most definitely not be ideal).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I did use that to configure visual studio to use 7.1.

Comment: Well thats good, but it leaves me as stymied as you. Are you using an environment-exploiting tools for code scanning or coverage analysis (like BullsEye). That can also cause issues as well, but its a total guess on my part.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sadly, no :/, otherwise I'd consider uninstalling those. This issue has come up once before when I was using directshow baseclasses and the only solution I found was to reinstall VS. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry couldn't be more help. When everything else is taken away (fluff-wise) all VS really becomes is a front-end to running cl.exe via msbuild. I'd be half-tempted to completely toast all the VC environment variables (VCInstallDir, VCToolsDir, etc) to reference *only* the Windows SDK folders, but that was what the Configuration Tool mentioned a few posts back is supposed to do for you. Anyway, total bummer, sir. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: So.. reinstalling visual studio did not do it. Now I am really confused.

Comment: WCHAR is an alias for wchar_t.  Things go wrong when it is not.  C/C++, Language, Treat wchar_t as Built-In Type setting should be Yes, the default.

Comment: @HansPassant This was set to yes - still creating the error though